# How to host socket.io on website hosting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, websocket

Hello I already create 2 Dimension online game client and server and I want to test it by uploading server and client on the internet, because now I load everything on xampp and nodejs localhost:8080. Maybe someone know how to put it on web hosting.

THANKS :)

Comment: Look at [surge.sh](https://surge.sh) for simple website hosting, but don't ask questions like this... they're off-topic (see [help/on-topic]).

Comment: thanks I will try it:)

Comment: please post answer then i could mark it as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options to host a website. If you don't want to use your own virtual server that you will have to configure, you can use `heroku`. Else you could try hosting on `Digital Ocean`. They are vps providers, you should have some knowledge of linux to do that or simply use google. There are many digital ocean tutorials on how to install nodeJS on the vps and configure it for production. I recommend reading this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04. The pros of using a vps is simply more resources for the same price and more functionality in the future.
Bare in mind that socket.io is also using websockets instead of just HTTP. If you choose to try and host it on your very own machine, you will have to add some configuration to your nginx server. The basics options required inside the configuration of the server are:

```
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

Comment: Ty, I will mark this post as answer in 7min.